# How to say "Where/in which" in this context?

Tags: translation, relative-clause

Example:

> The text talks about the advance of private schools, Where/in which the demand on study places has increased.

*Where/in which* in this case does not refer to a place or to a time. So What word can be equivalent to *Where/in which* in this case?
In this Case i want to make a "Relativsatz" using a connector inorder to make two equal related sentences not cause-effect.

Related Question:

Is this expression frequently used in german or is it rare?

Comment: I made an edit by changing education to private schools

Answer (score 1):

When interpreting your equation as "The demand on study places has increased, that's why text talks about the advance of education", then I would translate "as" in your context with the german equivalents "da / weil", so:

> Der Text spricht vom Fortschritt der Bildung, **da / weil** die Nachfrage an Studienplätzen gestiegen ist.

In my opinion "indem" doesn't really match in this context, because it is used for following two matters:

1) to indicate in the clause the means or circumstances necessary for the matter referred to in the main sentence.

2) to express that the operations mentioned in the subordinate sentence and those mentioned in the main sentence take place simultaneously.

"Da / weil" is generally often used in German, especially to connect main clauses to clauses

Comment: I got the equation as: The demand on study places has increased -> text talks about the advance of education

Comment: In your answer the second clause is the cause of the advance.I don't want to make a cause effect clause but relative clause

Comment: @HussienChahin, this is also the problem I have with this answer. :-)

Comment: Then see Janka's answer :) Matches more then

Answer (score 1):

*The text talks about the advance of education, as/in which the demand on study places has increased.*

> Der Text handelt von der Verbesserung der Bildungssituation, **in deren Folge** der Bedarf an Studienplätzen zugenommen hat.

You are talking about the equation:

*Verbesserung der Bildungssituation* → *Bedarf an Studienplätzen hat zugenommen*

This arrow is even called **Folgepfeil** in German.

Comment: This is not th equation!!The equation is: development of educationsystem=the increase in demand on places.I want a connector who can connect these two equal sentences

Comment: The English sentence says the education has advanced and the increased demand on study places was a (by-)product.  The German sentence says exactly the same.

Comment: Janka is right in my opinion

Comment: I have edited the question,maybe "as" have the impression that want a cause effect sentence.

Comment: This makes not so much of a difference. English *in which* leads a clause explaining parts or products.