# Which of these relative pronouns "In denen" "wo" and "bei denen" fits the most in this context?

Tags: relative-clause, context

> Der Text geht um den Fortschritt der Privatschulen, bei denen/in denen/wo die Nachfrage nach Plätzen gestiegen ist.

Comment: Only _bei denen_ works here. Nonetheless, there are several other orthographic and grammatic errors in this sentence.

Comment: What's the difference to your other [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/43572)?

Comment: In the other question the english translation to german didn't serve the meaning, so maybe giving some suggestions and translating from german could give the correct meaning

Answer (score 2):

`bei denen` is the only possible pronoun.

`in denen` would be `inside the schools`.

`wo` is informally possible but should be avoided whenever possible, since this is local (very often used in Brandenburg (and Berlin))

However I recommend that you rewrite your sentence to something like:
`Der Text handelt von dem Fortschritt der Privatschulen, bei denen die Nachfrage nach Plätzen gestiegen ist.`

`geht um` does not sound well.

Comment: Good answer but how frequent could this relative pronoun in this case be used in writing or speaking ?

Comment: Since this relative pronoun is quite significant, you should not use it to often. I recommend that you have a maximum of one appearance per sentence or better one appearance per 2-3 sentences. Otherwise you would have to rewrite your sentence. For example, if you had already used `bei denen` before your example sentence, you could write: `Der Text handelt davon, dass die Nachfrage von Plätzen an Privatschulen gestiegen ist.`   I hope I could help you.